# How to keep unique values in Excel, horizontally?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following data:

```
Cat   Dog   Monkey Monkey    Bird       Dog
Dog   Frog  Bird   Alligator Frog       Alligator
Shark Bird  Bird   Monkey    Alligator
```

I want to grab the unique values horizontally (output):

```
Cat   Dog    Monkey    Bird
Dog   Frog   Bird      Alligator
Shark Bird   Monkey    Alligator
```

I have tried Data > Advanced Filter > Copy to another location and selected Unique records only. But that didn't work. Also tried "transpose" and "unique" formulas, but that was even worse and wasn't close to what I wanted at all.

Any ideas? I've never tried macros, but I suppose if there's no other way, I could give it a go if anyone has the vba to share.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example: `=UNIQUE(A1:F1,TRUE)`  and fill down

Comment: Nevermind, I deleted that comment! Works great, thanks Tim! How do I choose you as the correct answer so I can close this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UNIQUE()` should work fine.

Eg:

```
=UNIQUE(A1:F1,TRUE)
```

and fill down

Comment: You might want to add an empty string `=UNIQUE(A1:F1,TRUE)&""` to avoid getting zero values if cells are empty  :-)